# TypeORM migration run error with function now() for add timestamp column

Tags: node.js, typescript, sqlite, typeorm

I'm trying to run a migration for add a column **updated_at** on my project and is showing the error below:

[image]

migration 1692382767691-AddUpdatedAtToUsers.ts

```
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner, TableColumn } from 'typeorm'

export class AddUpdatedAtToUsers1692382767691 implements MigrationInterface {
  async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.addColumn(
      'users',
      new TableColumn({
        name: 'updated_at',
        type: 'timestamp',
        default: 'now()',
      })
    )
  }

  async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.dropColumn('users', 'updated_at')
  }
}
```

data-source.ts

```
import 'reflect-metadata'
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm'

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: 'sqlite',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 4001,
  username: 'root',
  password: 'root',
  database: './src/database/database.sqlite',
  synchronize: false,
  logging: false,
  entities: ['./src/models/**.ts'],
  migrations: ['./src/database/migrations/**.ts'],
})
```

I'm not not understanding the error because the migration that created the table if was executed and also uses `default: 'now()'`. I appreciate help or suggestions.